# Time taken for deleting and truncating records in oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle9i

How much time will it take to delete and truncate 43GB of data in oracle

Comment: Truncate will be fast (but quite how fast depends on system load etc.); delete will be (probably much, much) slower, but how much slower is anyone's guess with no information about the platform, data, indexes, triggers, constraints, available undo/rollback... pretty much 'how long is a piece of string?'. Even the Oracle docs only say 'Removing rows with the TRUNCATE statement can be faster than removing all rows with the DELETE statement, especially if the table has numerous triggers, indexes, and other dependencies'.

Comment: Thanks Alex. Lets say the delete is taking 20 hrs for deleting 43GB of data then can you tell me approximate time when using truncate?
consider no dependency for the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `TRUNCATE` is a DDL command, it will complete almost instantly-- almost certainly less than a few seconds unless you have an exceptionally large number of extents.  Of course, that assumes that truncating the table is a valid option-- `TRUNCATE` cannot be rolled back, you cannot apply a `WHERE` clause to delete data selectively, the table cannot have any foreign key constraints, etc.

How long it will take to `DELETE` every row in the table depends heavily on your system.  As Alex Poole pointed out in the comments,  it will depend on system load, the number of indexes, the number of triggers, the number of constraints, etc.

Comment: Thanks Justin and Alex ...
It really helped...
Thought it seems to be a simple question, it needs a lot of research and hence i posted here. I got less responces, but valuable responces